# logging getLogger does not output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to setup a logging mechanism for a python module.

Following is the example code that I have written to setup logging

```
import logging

def init_logger(logger):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s')
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('test_logging.log')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def foo1():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.info('Test Info')
    logger.debug('Test Debug')
    logger.error('Test Error')


def foo2():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.info('Test Info')
    logger.debug('Test Debug')
    logger.error('Test Error')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    init_logger(logger)
    foo1()
    foo2()
```

I expect the logging to print info level and above to stdout and debug level and above to be written to the log file. But what I see is that only error level is outputted to both stdout and log file.

```
2019-08-13 11:20:07,775 - ERROR - test_logger.py - foo1 - Test Error
2019-08-13 11:20:07,776 - ERROR - test_logger.py - foo2 - Test Error
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) `getLogger` should return the same instance of logger. I even tried to create a new instance for the first time like `logger = logging.Logger(__name__)` but no luck with that. I am not understanding what am I missing here.

Comment: So you suggest I need to set the `basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`?

Comment: I suppose you need `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` somewhere in the very beginning. Otherwise you have level `WARNING` from root logger because initial level value is 0 (NOTSET) which is also `False` so it is illegal value according to `logging` module logic - function `getEffectiveLevel` defines the logic. So you can't initialize level with `getLogger` and must use `logger.setLevel` or `logging.basicConfig`. The feature should be documented I guess but it is not.

Comment: Setting the level to `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in `__main__` before `init_logger` is called works. Thanks. Please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you must use `logging.basicConfig(level=...)` or `logger.setLevel` in your code.

When you use `logging.getLogger('some_name')` for the first time you create a new logger with `level = NOTSET = 0`.

```
# logging module source code
class Logger(Filterer):
    def __init__(self, name, level=NOTSET):
        ...
```

`logging.NOTSET` seems to be a valid level value but it is not. Actually it is illegal value that says that logger is not enabled to log anything and forces logger to use level from parent logger (root logger). This logic is defined in `Looger.getEffectiveLevel` method:

```
# logging module source code
def getEffectiveLevel(self):
    logger = self
    while logger:
        if logger.level:  # 0 gives False here
            return logger.level
        logger = logger.parent  # 0 makes this line reachable
    return NOTSET
```

Root logger has `level=WARNING` so newly created loggers inherit this level:

```
# logging module source code
root = RootLogger(WARNING)
```

`logging.getLogger` does not allow you to specify logging level. So you have to use `logging.basicConfig` to modify root logger or `logger.setLevel` to modify newly created logger somewhere in the very beginning of the script.

I guess the feature should be documented in logging module guides/documentation.